# URL not showing correctly in latex IEEEtrans (both URL and Hyperref packages not working)

Tags: bibtex, url

I am working on a article using IEEEtrans template in overleaf, but I just noticed that a technical report reference with a URL doesn't compile correctly:

```
%Smith2040
@electronic{Smith2040,

 author   = "Smith, Matthew Nitch",

title     = "The number of cars worldwide is set to double by 2040",

url       = "\url{https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2016/04/the-number-of-cars-worldwide-is-set-to-double-by-2040}"
}
```

[image: the url is printed as is, with \url{} also.]

I get the aforementioned problem when using `\usepackage{url}`.
But, when using `\usepackage{hyperref}` I get fatal error.

[image: Fatal error when using Hyperref package]
is there a solution?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Could you please add a minimal example which reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `IEEEtran` bibliography style and the [hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package, it's a mistake to encase the contents of the `url` field in a `\url{...}` wrapper. You should just write

```
url = "https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2016/04/the-number-of-cars-worldwide-is-set-to-double-by-2040",
```

[image]

Incidentally, I think it would be a really good idea for you to backfill the `year` and `organization` fields of this entry.

The following example loads the `xurl` package, rather than the `url` package. The only difference is that the former allows linebreaks inside a formatted URL string at *any letter*.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{testbib.bib}
@electronic{Smith2040,
  author= "Smith, Matthew Nitch",
  title = "The number of cars worldwide is set to double by 2040",
  year  = 2016,
  organization = "World Economic Forum",
  url   = "https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2016/04/the-number-of-cars-worldwide-is-set-to-double-by-2040" 
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[spaces,hyphens]{xurl} % allow arbitrary line breaks in a formatted URL string
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{Smith2040}
\bibliography{testbib}
\end{document}
```